# 401 - Unauthorised error during Jmeter replay

Tags: jmeter

I m trying record my appling by usernamer and password, few of the requests are failing during rapplay with 401 Unauthersise error where during recording getting the 304 status code and response message: Not modified and 200 status code.

During recording Authersisation manager also generated as taaxhed in this post

When I am trying to  replace my username and password also it's getting 401 unauthersied issue

Please help me to overcome the issue

Thanks[Autherisation manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IS4cj.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

HTTP Authorization only might be not sufficient for logging in, modern web applications heavily rely on dynamic parameters which are used for the client-side state tracking or security reasons. So record the same scenario one more time and compare the resulting [.jmx test scripts](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JmxTestPlan). All parameters which will differ are a subject to [correlation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start), you will need to extract the dynamic values using suitable JMeter [Post-Processors](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) and replace recorded hard-coded values with [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) originating from the Post-Processors.

Also make sure to add a [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-http-cookie-manager-jmeter) to your test plan, it does correlation of [Set-Cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie) and [Cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cookie) header automatically.